# Plotting color pattern graph

Tags: python, r, numpy

I know Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but I am really stuck with this one and I have no clue how I can draw a map like this:

[image]

Where the color code is based on the p-value; the smaller the p-value, the brighter the color. The size of the dot is determined by the percentage overlap.

I have data of 3 samples, like this:

```
            Sample1                  Sample2                  Sample3   
Description percentage    p-value    Percentage    p-value    Percentage    p-value
Trendy      0.1585        0          0.1646        1.11E-016  0.2397        6.41E-014
nonTrendy   0.219         5.55E-016                           0.2203        9.84E-012
Specific    0.1713        9.99E-016  0.162         2.74E-011  0.1838        1.73E-012
nonspecific 0.2119        3.02E-013  0.1356        0.0000613  0.2044        1.1E-011
Robotics    0.1632        7.85E-013  0.1263        0.00000361 0.2158        0
human       0.2533        7.25E-012  0.1733        0.0000218  0.2069        4.16E-008
```

For each sample I have a percentage overlap(yes this percentage has not been multiplied by 100 so it is on scale of 1) and a p-value.

Also, few samples might have missing values (both for percentage and p-value). This happens due to absence of significant overlaps, as in the case of `sample2` of `nonTrendy`.

Please help me getting a figure like the one in attachment.

Comment: This is probably a `ggplot2` plot made in R, with `geom_point` and mapping the `size` and `color` (and, of course, `x` and `y`) aesthetics. Search and you'll find :-) (Why don't you ask the author of the article you found this graph in, if she would share the relevant code with you?)

Comment: The email just bounces back :(

Comment: Poor luck. But still, this graph is easy enough to construct. Remember to use factors for the x and y scales to get the right ordering along the axes, and `theme_bw()` to get rid of the default gray background. You might also need the `reshape` package to, well, reshape your data for usage in `ggplot2`.

Comment: Why a vote to close this question?????????????? Baffling

Comment: I didn't vote, but I assume this question is too specific to attract general interest. Also, the data could be formatted better (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/946850), and the Python tag doesn't quite fit. These are also the reasons why I comment instead of answering your question.

Comment: Well python tag was for numpy libraries, that can be used.

Comment: There are not enough values in the `nonTrendy` row.

Comment: @Sven: sample 2 in non trendy does not have any value that is why its values are missing, in R I can put NaN but I don't know what is the replacement in python or in other languages. Thank you

Comment: @Angelo You could use `np.nan` from the numpy package, or alternatively `None`, although I'd recommend the first one.

Comment: @nordev Thank you, but the basic question is still unsolved how can i plot it I was looking into ggplot2 but still no breakthrough from my end

Comment: If you provide the community with some good data, which we can readily paste into our own R session, you'll get an answer soon enough. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Angelo Because it included an error. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script creates a plot in R. It does not exactly look like your example plot, but it can be modified.

```
text <- "Sample1     Sample2     Sample3     
Description percentage  p-value Percentage  p-value Percentage  p-value
Trendy  0.1585  0   0.1646  1.11E-016   0.2397  6.41E-014
nonTrendy   0.219   5.55E-016   NA     NA   0.2203  9.84E-012
Specific    0.1713  9.99E-016   0.162   2.74E-011   0.1838  1.73E-012
nonspecific 0.2119  3.02E-013   0.1356  0.0000613   0.2044  1.1E-011
Robotics    0.1632  7.85E-013   0.1263  0.00000361  0.2158  0
human   0.2533  7.25E-012   0.1733  0.0000218   0.2069  4.16E-008"
```

Note. Two `NA`s were added to the data.

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(text), 8)
strings <- strsplit(lines, " +")
sam <- strings[[1]]
des <- unlist(lapply(strings[-1], "[", 1))
coln <- sub("-", "", strings[[2]][-1][1:2])
val <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strings[-(1:2)], function(x) as.numeric(x[-1])))

perc <- as.vector(val[ , as.logical(seq(ncol(val)) %% 2)])
pval <- as.vector(val[ , !seq(ncol(val)) %% 2])

dat <- setNames(data.frame(des[-1], perc, pval), c(des[1], coln))
dat$sample <- rep(sam, each = nrow(val))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(colour = pvalue, size = percentage, 
                x = sample, y = Description)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: last question, instead of space separated data(as in example), how can I deal with tab separated data (is it possible to read the data through a tab separated file and plot the same). Thank you

Comment: @Angelo It should work if you replace `" +"`in the `strsplit` function with `"\t"`.

Comment: Thank you, it did work. One more How can I change the colour code to red instead of blue?

Comment: @Angelo Add `scale_colour_continuous(high = "red")` to the plot.

Comment: Definitely last one :) Sorry to bother you again, is their a way to reduce the white spaces in figure. Actually a lot of wgite spaces are spoiling the party :(

Comment: @Angelo You can decrease the size of the figure (it's easy to do it in the plot window).

Comment: Is their a way to block the ggplot from sorting the data but plotting as the entered order of data.

Comment: @Angelo You can manually specify the order of the factor levels with the `factor` function. This has to be done before plotting. For example, `myfactor <- factor(myfactor, levels = c("a", "c", "d", "b")`.

Comment: How do I incorporate it in this code so that it takes the order of input data and no sorting is done. Kindly help

Comment: @Angelo `dat$Description <- factor(dat$Description, levels = rev(c("Trendy", "nonTrendy", "Specific", "nonspecific", "Robotics", "human")))
`